# Impact of consistency level on performance

Tags: cassandra

Is there a benchmark which shows the difference in write throughput when consistency level is ONE vs LOCAL_QUORUM? In both cases RF should be the same (e.g. RF=3)?

P.S. I'm not interested in latency, already found a lot of articles on that including the measure of eventuality of eventually consistent systems.

Comment: I would be interested in such results too. My intuition leads me to believe that, since no matter the consistency, both reads and writes are directed to all replicas, the raw request rate should be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of this is going to be case-specific, as there are a number of variables here. This would be an easy test to set up using your specific application and environment, so my suggestion would be to run your own benchmark.

Comment: This is a very frustrating answer. *All* results are case-specific. That is why benchmarks have been invented: It gives the reader at least an idea of what could be expected in other cases.

Comment: I understand your frustration, but you must realize that your results would vary widely depending on the size of your cluster, your network latency/bandwidth (and the consistency of it), characteristics of the data itself, machine configuration, Cassandra configuration, and many other factors.  I would argue that benchmarks are largely irrelevant for this reason, and especially so in a distributed system like Cassandra.

Comment: Your argument could be used to void any benchmark, like SPEC, HPL, Apache Benchmark, etc. Still, people have considered it more useful to have some clue (i.e., at least one data point) than no clue at all. I would love to see an answer like: On my cluster with this configuration I saw x-fold increase in write throughput. This would give way more information than "in depends".

Comment: Actually I did some tests and write throughput is almost the same for different consistency levels. Only latency depends on consistency level. Writes always propagate to all replicas so the work done by the cluster is the same when CL is ONE or QUORUM.